spearman's rho plot
I have done a Spearman correlation and need a scatterplot with a line matching the Spearman's rho.
How can I do this?
> db
   id Var_1  Var_2  Var_3 Var_4
1   5  8.17  83.08  10.28 19.81
2   6  4.06  42.30   2.72 28.92
3  17  6.06  62.43   4.55 23.10
4  18 10.88  61.12  15.96 23.50
5  27 10.67  49.29   1.99 19.50
6  30  2.85  57.22  13.05 19.90
7  37  7.26  53.79  13.91 22.30
8  40 28.77 146.45 558.33 33.10
9  41  5.26  42.87   7.03 23.40
10 42 21.38  70.32  12.60 20.00

> cor.test(db$Var_4, db$Var_2, method=c("spearman"))

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  db$Var_4 and db$Var_2
S = 168, p-value = 0.9728
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
        rho 
-0.01818182 




I think you misunderstand what Spearman's rho means. There is not really a line which matches it. It does not assume a linear relationship.

You cannot do more than plot(db$Var_4, db$Var_2)

The line on that plot looks to just be a linear line-of-best-fit - plot(db$Var_4, db$Var_2); abline(lm(Var_2 ~ Var_4, data=db))

continuing on my first comment: and plot(rank(db$Var_4), rank(db$Var_2)); plot(db$Var_4-db$Var_2); plot(db$Var_2-db$Var_4).

@Axeman thank you. so is there a way to plot this result?

@Friede What do these plots you suggest represent?

You might want to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient

@ArTu I would just plot the scatterplot without the line, and report the correlation in the text.

Use ‘abline’ to manually add lines to your plot.
db <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
   id Var_1  Var_2  Var_3 Var_4
5  8.17  83.08  10.28 19.81
6  4.06  42.30   2.72 28.92
17  6.06  62.43   4.55 23.10
18 10.88  61.12  15.96 23.50
27 10.67  49.29   1.99 19.50
30  2.85  57.22  13.05 19.90
37  7.26  53.79  13.91 22.30
40 28.77 146.45 558.33 33.10
41  5.26  42.87   7.03 23.40
42 21.38  70.32  12.60 20.00")

rho <- cor(db$Var_4, db$Var_2, method=c("spearman"))

Since Spearman's correlation coefficient is based on the ranks, we transform the data to ranks before plotting.
db.rank <- dplyr::mutate(db, across(starts_with("Var"), rank))

a <- mean(db.rank$Var_2)

plot(db.rank$Var_4, db.rank$Var_2,
     main="Scatter plot of ranks\nSpearman's correlation: -0.15"))
abline(a=a, b=rho, col="red")




It seems to me that this line is entirely meaningless. Rho is not interpretable as the slope on the data scale. Am I mistaken?

I have never consciously seen such a visulation. Do you have a reference?

The e-book to {smplot} show a standard technique (which I personally do not like): https://smin95.github.io/dataviz/basics-of-ggplot2-and-correlation-plot.html#reporting-statistics-from-a-paired-correlation

Spearman’s rho is one of many measures of the “relationship” between two variables. The red line provides this visually, as requested by the OP.

Now try this plot on x/y data that is strongly correlated, using the same scale, and tell me if that red line still makes sense.

Just because it measures the "relationship" does not mean it is interpretable as a slope on the data scale. E.g. if you divide the y-axis by 1000, the correlation does not change, yet the slope will suddenly look much steeper.

It answers the question, @Axeman. Why divide the y-axis by 1,000? The 2 variables are on the same scale. That’s why the OP accepted my answer.

Just play around with a few datasets of different scales and you'll see pretty quickly that this isn't doing what you may think. OP's x and y scales differ by a factor ~50 (ratio of variances). Here is another example where the scale only differs by a factor 8: m <- MASS::mvrnorm(100, c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, 2.82, 2.82, 8), 2)); plot(m); abline(0, cor(m[, 1], m[, 2], method = 'spearman')). Does that look right to you? What does the line mean?
